# error on arcpy.FeatureSet() load from feature service: cannot open table for load

Tags: arcpy, feature-service, feature-set

I am trying to pull data from a feature service into a feature set, and the following was working perfect:

```
fsURL = baseURL + query
fs = arcpy.FeatureSet()
fs.load(fsURL)
```

but all of a sudden, this same, unchanged code now throws the error:

"RuntimeError: RecordSetObject: Cannot open table for load"

The feature service is in a secure rest end point, that I have working by generating a secure token, and when I print out the URL I want to hit, I can see the data I need, but for some reason now get that error.  I had this working previously, and as far as I know no code in this area, no changes to the database,  and no software has changed to cause this to now not work.

I've researched this, and found other similar issues, with either no resolution, or discovered a software version change, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is your case. What is in the fsURL right before it breaks?  Does it work if you just plop the fsURL in a browser?
There seems to be something different at 10.61 AGS server rest apis, They can no longer use > or < and you need to use between.     Try something like.
  where = 'OBJECTID between ' + 1 + ' and ' + 999

Answer (score 1):

Just got this error again, after it had been working before (now on a Prod server, but set up exactly like the other env).  The fsURL can be pasted in a browser and after entering credentials the feature service pulls up.  Credentials for the script are handed in within the fsURL (after being a token has been generated) so the script should be able to open the feature service directly.  I found one article from esri on this issue (https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000018476) stating that you need to use a feature service, not a map service, which I am, so I do not know why this is not working.  This IS working on another server, so I do not think it is a script issue, just not sure what else it could be.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? I am experiencing the same issue with the same kind of data. Thanks.